# Reliable way to check the Internet connection for or after an AJAX requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, connection

is there way to check the Internet connection before an AJAX request or getting an error code after the operation? It should be tested with Javascript or JQuery.

I have tried navigator.onLine which does not work well. It also returns true if there is no connection.

Comment: I would try sending a request to a site you know is up i.e. a google service and then read the returned status code from that.

Comment: If you're serving the page on a server outside the clients LAN, chances are they are online

Comment: There is no reliable way. For example, requesting from another site first determines if that site is responding to you. If it doesn't, does that mean ... a) no internet connection, b) that site is down, or c) that site is up but didn't respond to your request (temporary glitch?) So, there's every chance you can get a false negative

Comment: What is the best error code to handle a failure?

Comment: what do you mean by error code?

Comment: After an AJAX requests. If there is failure it should return an error code

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, there is no return- How do **you** handle AJAX errors in general? - note: jQueery.Ajax does not call the error handler _for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests_ - so that's a possible added wrinkle

Comment: At the moment I check the values before starting a request.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno how to handle this before starting an AJAX request. Here is another way of achieving the same using `.error` in `jQuery.ajax`. Pseudo code

```
var timeInterval = 5000,
    step = 1,
    timeOutID;

function DoSomething() {
    $.ajax({
        //...
        timeout: 5000;
        //...
    }).done(function (data) {
        step = 1; // reset delay
        //process your data
    }).error(function (xhr, status, error) {
        //Houston in the blind!
        if (status == "timeout") {
            if (timeOutID) window.clearTimeout(timeOutID);
            timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function () {
                DoSomething();
            }, (timeInterval * step++)); //to increase delay on each consecutive call
        }
    });
}
```

Its because as per jQuery docs, we have a `textStatus == "timeout"`

> error   Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String
>   errorThrown )
>
> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives
>   three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a
>   string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second
>   argument (besides `null`) are ***`"timeout"`***, `"error"`, `"abort"`, and
>   `"parsererror"`. When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the
>   textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal
>   Server Error."

---

Using Vanilla JS

```
var timeInterval = 5000,
    step = 1,
    timeOutID;

function DoSomething() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            step = 1; // reset delay
            //process your data
        }
    };

    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    xhr.timeout = 5000; // this is not our variable "timeInterval", its the request timeout
    xhr.ontimeout = function () {
        if (timeOutID) window.clearTimeout(timeOutID);
        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function () {
            DoSomething();
        }, (timeInterval * step++));
    }
    xhr.send(json);
}
```